# Utility in Behringer X32 Edit

Tags: console

[image]

So I have these utilities on the left side of the screen, like "All", "User2", ect.. does anyone know how I can make more "Users" available to use? There are currently only two. I looked it up, they are called "Fader Banks", but I can't seem to be able to add more.

Comment: Have you read the manual? It's usually the place to go. When I buy something, I HAVE T0 read the manual front-to-back. Maybe that's just me. BTW, I don't even know what these users are. Like presets for the layout etc?

Answer (score 1):

> does anyone know how I can make more "Users" available to use? There are currently only two.

You can't. X32 Edit does not allow defining new user layers, there are only the two.